# Integrate XML into existing views

Tags: model-view-controller, rest, grails

I'm converting a Grails app to use the REST architecture, and would like to use the existing views.

All the REST tutorials I've come across deal with URL redirects and controller actions.  Problem is, none concern themselves with showing the data, which is the whole point!

When I access the information, it shows up as well formed XML.  How can I use that with existing views?

Answer (score 1):

Well, because it's the same thing.

i.e. localhost/bookstore/book/1 will call show of the book controller

- If you call it from a browser it will render the html view.
- If you call with with curl or postman (chrome) and add:
   Accept: text/xml
   Content-Type: text/xml
  it will return XML

Now if you want to call a rest action from a view, well, that is an ajax problem. So check jquery ajax documentation...